How can this open map characterization be explained or interpreted?
I'm an undergrad mathematics student, I took a general topology course a few months ago, and I'm now reviewing topological spaces to prepare for functional analysis.
I remember coming across the following proposition during the course:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces, and let $f$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$. The following statements are equivalant. (i) $f$ is an open map.  (ii) For all subsets $B$ of $Y$, and for all closed sets $F$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq F$, there exists a closed set $D$ of $Y$ such that $ B \subseteq D $ and $ f^{-1}(D) \subseteq F$.

I understand the proof of this proposition, however, I never quite got why it's important, or how it's useful. There's even another proposition analogous to this one for closed maps, and I don't understand it either. I really appreciate it if anyone could explain the importance/implications of this proposition, and if it relates to any other important result.

Just a remark, not at all an answer: (ii) is equivalent to $$\forall B\subseteq Y\quad f^{-1}(\overline B)\subseteq\overline{f^{-1}(B)}.$$ Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393354 and the linked posts.
